# MYSQL qlikview assign variable

Tags: mysql, qlikview

Im having problems with this.

I have this qlikview script which is run on the 15th of every month. This script intends to automatically take the last date of the previous month in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'. 
For example today is 15th January 2017. I will run my script and it will give me a date of 31th December 2016 in the format 2016-12-31.
If it is 15th December 2016, I will get 30th November 2016 in the format 2016-11-30.

I want to set the date retrieved as a variable in the format yyyy-mm-dd to be used in another query.

Basically I tried

```
SET @vLastDate = DATE_FORMAT(select last_day(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

but I receive an error that it does not execute. I am doing this in qlikview. Please help me identify my problem thank you.

Comment: How do you know it "does not work"?

Comment: I receive an error that the qlikview script does not execute

Comment: That was the entire error message? Well that sucks...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute mysql functions in qlikview? That won't work.

Try in QV script:

```
let vLastDate = MonthEnd(AddMonths(Today(),-1));
```

If you need to change the date format, play around with the Date#() function, probably something like Date#(Field, 'YYYY-MM-DD'). Today() returns YYYY-MM-DD format so it will probably be fine.